# Delete a row and a column at the same time in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to delete a row and a column of a matrix at the same time ?

**Example:**

```
M = magic(3)

M =

   8   1   6
   3   5   7
   4   9   2
```

And with a **one-liner** remove the column 2 and the row 2 to obtain:

```
M = 

   8  6
   4  2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can supply an array of indices for the row and column indices and MATLAB will automatically return all permutations (usually an annoying feature, but a benefit here).

So you could do something like:

```
M([1 3], [1 3])
```

Or more flexible, you could use logical indexing

```
M([true false true], [true false true])
```

Or more generally (with potentially more rows and columns)

```
row = 2;        % Could be an array of rows to exclude
column = 2;     % Could be an array of columns to exclude

out = M(~ismember(1:size(M, 1), row), ~ismember(1:size(M, 2), column))
```